# numpy.linalg.solve for Decimal in Python

Tags: python, numpy, precision, equation-solving

Is there any way how to solve equations when a matrix **A** and a vector **b** is composed of decimal.Decimals?

My **A**:

```
array([[Decimal('-5266125828.168885444558615257'),
        Decimal('11312418445.69612428831109944'),
        Decimal('-8191751288.262710691535623734'),
        Decimal('1560333578.716706798387737854'),
        Decimal('975208486.697941748992336159'),
        Decimal('-390083394.6791766995969344634'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0')],
       [Decimal('0'), Decimal('-325069495.5659805829974453865'),
        Decimal('158922864.4989238405765288561'),
        Decimal('1574781111.852972602076513203'),
        Decimal('-2773926362.163034308244867295'),
        Decimal('1755375276.056295148186205086'),
        Decimal('-390083394.6791766995969344634'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0')],
       [Decimal('156033357.8716706798387737854'),
        Decimal('-723994780.5245519544519103641'),
        Decimal('1201456855.611864234758558147'),
        Decimal('-867545469.7664889799035822465'),
        Decimal('234050036.8075060197581606780'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0')],
       [Decimal('0'), Decimal('167178597.7196471569701147700'),
        Decimal('-734676014.4686534925353342956'),
        Decimal('1186171955.248925066121290511'),
        Decimal('-841579335.4594482731828906790'),
        Decimal('222904796.9595295426268196934'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0')],
       [Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('173370397.6351896442653042060'),
        Decimal('-742710221.9680346488896365366'),
        Decimal('1179881872.795040634583320290'),
        Decimal('-827255045.5061826852906182174'),
        Decimal('216712997.0439870553316302574'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0')],
       [Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('177310633.9450803179986065743'),
        Decimal('-748514643.1334464994519689103'),
        Decimal('1176697843.453714837627116356'),
        Decimal('-818266594.9994450377720819097'),
        Decimal('212772760.7340963815983278891'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0')],
       [Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('180038489.8519277075062774446'),
        Decimal('-752823665.6530310451939017410'),
        Decimal('1174866555.572194911803784863'),
        Decimal('-812126284.5983405662068175856'),
        Decimal('210044904.8272489920906570188'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0')],
       [Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('182038917.5169491264785694162'),
        Decimal('-756126094.2196071018557467436'),
        Decimal('1173717591.990233891676109474'),
        Decimal('-807674892.4498034894172971942'),
        Decimal('208044477.1622275731183650472'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0')],
       [Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('183568656.3196125645162044534'),
        Decimal('-758729273.2656650806733779223'),
        Decimal('1172949723.101053812974865220'),
        Decimal('-804303844.5145654318984217615'),
        Decimal('206514738.3595641350807300100'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0')],
       [Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('184776344.8480310682301268511'),
        Decimal('-760830391.3133147524723413401'),
        Decimal('1172411310.877857947542032944'),
        Decimal('-801664314.2437198946666260673'),
        Decimal('205307049.8311456313668076123'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0')],
       [Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('185753997.4662746188556830778'),
        Decimal('-762560174.6325251019871397825'),
        Decimal('1172019269.727685095160857515'),
        Decimal('-799542489.7743366927706521957'),
        Decimal('204329397.2129020807412513856'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0')],
       [Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('186561623.5422149432854903955'),
        Decimal('-764008161.0261182502995765811'),
        Decimal('1171724979.480551560793060231'),
        Decimal('-797800213.1336100100904181135'),
        Decimal('203521771.1369617563114440679'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0')],
       [Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('187240029.4460048158065285424'),
        Decimal('-765237517.6771919485468950510'),
        Decimal('1171498450.900503464229513580'),
        Decimal('-796344327.9024882152795529928'),
        Decimal('202843365.2331718837904059210'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0')],
       [Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('187817930.7714554479540795564'),
        Decimal('-766293986.6211983064885976712'),
        Decimal('1171320371.677253491656638601'),
        Decimal('-795109779.7352318847649753936'),
        Decimal('202265463.9077212516428549070'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0')],
       [Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('188316121.5692577170467959478'),
        Decimal('-767211459.0992147249278671672'),
        Decimal('1171177849.661023979170344257'),
        Decimal('-794049785.2409859538394115532'),
        Decimal('201767273.1099189825501385156'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0')],
       [Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('188750029.6834725965791618371'),
        Decimal('-768015556.0911829122271355112'),
        Decimal('1171062012.122190195980391183'),
        Decimal('-793129850.7101839833501901352'),
        Decimal('201333364.9957041030177726263'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0')],
       [Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('189131342.8747523391985136792'),
        Decimal('-768725993.0205441151307816094'),
        Decimal('1170966590.639328403105949275'),
        Decimal('-792323992.2979609875721021294'),
        Decimal('200952051.8044243603984207842'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0')],
       [Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('189469077.4156001112327967394'),
        Decimal('-769358181.2445607013718010984'),
        Decimal('1170887054.885985897484022875'),
        Decimal('-791612268.3206018957091562400'),
        Decimal('200614317.2635765883641377240'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0')],
       [Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('189770300.1141940700741843335'),
        Decimal('-769924337.4814003063767816301'),
        Decimal('1170820064.818653804706942082'),
        Decimal('-790979122.0164301979270949151'),
        Decimal('200313094.5649826295227501299'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0')],
       [Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('-1'), Decimal('2'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('-2'), Decimal('1')],
       [Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('1'),
        Decimal('-2'), Decimal('1'), Decimal('0')],
       [Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0.5'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('-0.5'), Decimal('0')],
       [Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'),
        Decimal('1'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0')]], dtype=object)
```

and my **b**:

```
array([Decimal('28.46878984613170937317471770'),
       Decimal('85.40636953839512811952415308'),
       Decimal('142.3439492306585468658735885'),
       Decimal('199.2815289229219656122230239'),
       Decimal('256.2191086151853843585724593'),
       Decimal('313.1566883074488031049218947'),
       Decimal('370.0942679997122218512713301'),
       Decimal('427.0318476919756405976207655'),
       Decimal('483.9694273842390593439702009'),
       Decimal('540.9070070765024780903196363'),
       Decimal('597.8445867687658968366690717'),
       Decimal('654.7821664610293155830185071'),
       Decimal('711.7197461532927343293679427'),
       Decimal('768.6573258455561530757173780'),
       Decimal('825.5949055378195718220668132'),
       Decimal('882.5324852300829905684162485'),
       Decimal('939.4700649223464093147656844'),
       Decimal('996.4076446146098280611151197'),
       Decimal('1053.345224306873246807464555'), Decimal('0'),
       Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0')], dtype=object)
```

I need to maintain this precision level. Obviously, numpy.linalg.solve doesn't work.
I am unable to find a solver that would work with decimal.Decimal. Lowering the precision might cause problems in the solution, therefore I need to have the result as precise as possible. I tried changing the dtype and from numpy array to list (which probably works better with decimal.Decimal), but couldn't solve it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you tried to change `dtype of numpy` before doing the calculation ?

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow Changing it to any dtype that would work for numpy.linalg.solve would decrease the precision :( I wanted to keep the decimal.Decimal as long as possible in order to keep the precision.

Comment: Any `dtype` other than the standards like `float` and `int` are `object` - regardless whether the elements are `Decimal`, or lists.  Compile array inverse uses floats, not objects.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, but that's the problem...numpy.linalg.solve works only with `float` and `int`, but is there any solver that would work with `Decimal`? Or how would you proceed with that? Because I found [general solver for ODEs](https://integratedmlai.com/system-of-equations-solution/), but there are lines that don't work with `Decimal`

Comment: You could use the scipy solver to get a starting value and use a brute force search for your Decimal precision.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason why you couldn't use the code in from [here](https://integratedmlai.com/system-of-equations-solution/).
You said some lines don't work with decimals, but with some small adjustment it seems to work just fine.

```
b = b.reshape(-1, 1)
n = len(A)

A_ = np.copy(A)
b_ = np.copy(b)

indices = list(range(n))  # allow flexible row referencing ***
for fd in range(n):  # fd stands for focus diagonal
    fdScaler = Decimal(1.0) / A_[fd][fd]
    # FIRST: scale fd row with fd inverse.
    for j in range(n):  # Use j to indicate column looping.
        A_[fd][j] *= fdScaler
    b_[fd][0] *= fdScaler

    # SECOND: operate on all rows except fd row.
    for i in indices[0:fd] + indices[fd + 1:]:  # *** skip fd row.
        crScaler = A_[i][fd]  # cr stands for "current row".
        for j in range(n):  # cr - crScaler*fdRow.
            A_[i][j] = A_[i][j] - crScaler * A_[fd][j]
        b_[i][0] = b_[i][0] - crScaler * b_[fd][0]
```

This is just copied from there, with small adjustments to work with arrays and decimals. The solution will then be in b_.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! I am new to Python, so couldn't figure it out myself. Appreciate it!